# Number of cliques of intersection graphs in hyperconvex metric spaces

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

(cross-posted from Math.SE)

I would like to find out if it is known whether intersection graphs of closed unit balls in [hyperconvex metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_metric_space) have polynomially many cliques.

A metric space is *hyperconvex*  (aka injective) if it is convex, and its closed balls have the "binary Helly property", i.e., if a collection of closed balls intersects pairwise, then they all do.

There is [some information](https://dmtcs.episciences.org/387) known about graphs "with few cliques" (i.e., polynomially many), and the relationship of this graph class to Helly intersection number, but I am wondering if the Helly property of balls in hyperconvex spaces implies that an intersection graph of closed balls in a hyperconvex space necessarily falls into this class.

[Spinrad](https://bookstore.ams.org/fim-19) argues that boxes (axis-parallel rectangles) in $\mathbb R^d$ having the Helly property implies that the number of maximal cliques of an $n$-vertex graph with [boxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxicity) $k$ is $O(n^k)$, however the only [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181281/proof-the-number-of-maximal-cliques-in-a-graph-with-boxicity-d-is-mathcalo) I'm aware of also heavily utilizes the geometry of $\mathbb R^d$. So the origin for my question is wondering if the Helly property of closed balls in hyperconvex spaces would yield a similar bound of polynomial size for the number of cliques of intersection graphs there.